# onAnimationRepeat() method not working

Tags: android, animation

onAnimationRepeat() method is not working. I have tested through logger that the method is not being accessed by android.
What am I doing wrong ?

**code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

       private TextView textView;
       String animText;
       private Animation fadeInAnimation;
       ArrayList<String> numList;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.animationText);
       numList=new ArrayList<String>();
       Random random = new Random();
               int num = random.nextInt(20);
               for(int i = 1; i <= num ; i++){
                       animText = String.valueOf(i);
                       numList.add(animText);
               }        
       doFadeEffectAnimation();
   }

   public void doFadeEffectAnimation(){

             textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.animationText);
             textView.setTextSize(50);
               fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in);
               fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                               // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                       }
                       @Override
                       public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       for (int i = 0; i < numList.size(); i++) {
                               textView.setText(numList.get(i));
                       }
                       }
                       @Override
                       public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                               // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                       }
               });
               textView.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);

       }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
       return true;
   }


}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <alpha
       android:duration="2000"
       android:fromAlpha="0.1"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:toAlpha="1.0"
       android:repeatCount="2"
      />

</set>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try calling ***doFadeEffectAnimation()*** from the onWindowFocusChanged() method, rather than calling it from onCreate() method...

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(final boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        doFadeEffectAnimation();
    }
}
```

Hope it may help to solve your problem...

Comment: your answer is out of scope to the question asked.

Comment: Once I had a similar situation, in my case the animation was not even starts, because I wrote the code in onCreate() method. After I changed my animation code from onCreate() to onWindowFocusChanged(), everything worked perfectly. I think, the issue you reported may be due to the same reasons that I faced.